# Magnetic circuit with multiple path

Tags: magnetic-fields

Let's image we have a usual magnetic circuit consisting of an rectangular c-shaped iron core, with a coil wound on it and a small air gap on the other side.

Now let's make another two variants:

1. We just put another identical coil next to the exiting one. So they are in a magnetic 'series' circuit.
2. We add another bar of iron into the c (making it a 'ℂ') and put an identical coil there. So they are in a magnetic 'parallel' circuit.

By intuition and my experience from permanent magnets, I would guess both variants result in doubling the magnetic flux and field strength at the air gap.  But the often named analogy to electric circuits would say they do not, and so my intuition is wrong.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to imagine the magnetic coil flux to be the equivalent to an electric current source, not a voltage source. Then, two current sources in parallel will double the current in the load (the air gap), and double the voltage across the load.

Comment: Yeah, then it is as you say.. but most textbooks (and wikipedia) give the analogy of a coil to a voltage source (eg magnetic "voltage"). These contradict each other, so only one model would be feasable I guess?

Comment: Yes. The voltage source analogy is incorrect. It's true that transformer coil ratios result in voltage ratios too, but that's only in AC circuits, and somewaht irrelevant to the concept of a "magnetic circuit".

Comment: Wikipedia for example gives a table of analogies, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_circuit#Summary_of_analogy   There is a "magentomotive force" (which is created by coils for example) and that is actually analogous to _volts_ there. So in that model, it is "voltage", not "current" that is the analogon to a magnet flux source (eg. a coil), and so the magnetic parallel circuit won't give more total flux. So that contradicts you're answer, but still I found it counterintuitive.

Comment: The nomenclature in Wikipedia is actually irrelevant, and the fact that the MMF and EMF are on the same line is also irrelvant and easily misunderstood when constructing magnetic and electric circuits. The total magnetic flux in the two paths (and the third path) is given by a closed integral enclosing both magnetic flux sources, which necessarily adds the two contributions, exactly like two electric current sources connected in parallel. The misconception here is saying that the two MMF sources are in series, which in turn leads to confusion wrt electric circuits.

Comment: When two coils are in parallel, the "center hole" can be thought of a region where wires of both coils go through, but in anti-parallel direction. So the net current is zero in the hole, and the overall current around the yoke is the same as for a single coil. That reinforces the "voltage" analogy, like two batteries in parallel give the same voltage. So in the end, putting a lot of same coils with same amperage in parallel does not create more flux over an air gap it seems. Putting more windings or more current on one coil in contrast does.

Comment: Thing is, the flux in the core may be the sum of both coil paths. But the air gap is analogous to the "resistor" in electric circuit, while the iron has a very low magnetic resistance to it's the "wire" in this analogy. Putting more sources in parallel would not raise the flux in the common path, like more batteries in parallel would not raise the current on a resistor driven by them. So flux does not increase with more coils. It even decreases in the coils, as it is split over all coils, as you say.